# Compare Columns name of Two DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, datatable

I have two datatables,

1. `dtSchema` datatable filled by ms-access database
2. `table`datatable filled by excel sheet

> `table` must have four columns named (SN, FN, DOB, Sec)

I want to compare the columns name of `table` with columns name of `dtSchema`.  The columns in `table` which are not matched with `dtSchema` place them in list.

```
foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
{
       isColumnMatch = false;
       foreach(DataColumn colDb in dtSchema.Columns)
       {
             if(col.ColumnName == colDb.ColumnName)
             {
             }
       }
```

}

I can compare the datatables column name. If `table` above four columns matched with `dtSchema`and the `table` has more than four columns then columns which are not matched must be placed in list.

Comment: What's the problem? what do you mean by "can't find the difference"?

Comment: You can enumerate through the columns of a DataTable using following : string[] names = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by a simple LINQ query, something like:

```
var tableColumnNames = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c=>c.ColumnName).ToList();
var schemaColumnNames = dtSchema.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c=>c.ColumnNames).ToList();

var unmatchedColumnNames = 
    from col in tableColumnNames where !schemaColumnNames.Contains(col) select col;
```

Comment: Where we check the four necessary columns (SN,FN,DOB,Sec).

Comment: It compares a set to a reference set, I don't know what you mean by necessary columns.

Comment: These  four columns are necessary. `dtSchema` has these columns. But i want to check if `table` has these four columns

Comment: Have you tried the code I provided? It returns columns that exist in table and not in dtSchema you can switch these two lists to have the columns which exist in dtSchema but not in the table. If you want all differences you can do it for both sides and join the results.

Comment: is there a way to check these four columns are exist in `table`?

Comment: One way could be adding these columns to another list and repeat the above for that list too.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to use any collection to save all those columns that are not matched so in case if columnName or title is not matched then you have to push it to some list. So at the end, you will have a list of unmatched columns

===== Updated ======

```
var filter= from firstDt in dt1.AsEnumerable()
        where !(from secondDt in dt2.AsEnumerable() select secondDt["Name"]).Contains(firstDt["Name"].ToString()) select firstDt; DataTable resultDt = filter.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: using LINQ the unmatched 'Name' fields of two tables.

Updating my answer accordinly.

Comment: Where do I get `Name` in linq query? U written **"Name"** in linq